# How to subset a data table according to several conditions

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question which is giving me unexpected troubles. The question, which seems imbarassingly simple, is that I would like to subset a `data.table` according to a few conditions. Let's consider this example; imagine I have a `data.table` like the one below. Now, I would like to extrapolate from it a subset such that a>=1045 and a<=1180 and (b=="c" or b=="d").

```
dt<-data.table(a=(1000:1200), b=sample(letters[1:3], size=201, replace=T))
```

I read the `data.table` guides and FAQ and searched the forum, but I don't seem to find anything which is relevant. I apologize in advance if you think the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
dt[a>=1045 & a <=1180 & b %chin% c('c', 'd')]
```

Or as @David Arenburg commented, `between` can be used

```
dt[between(a, 1045, 1180) & b %chin% c('c', 'd')]
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg I take your word.  If somebody complains, I will direct it towards you  :-)

Comment: Many thanks to both! :) I even tried before the code you suggested, but the reason why it didn't work was because my a column was a factor and the logical 'less or equal than' was not allowed.

Comment: @Riccardo `%chin%` works with `character` class and not on factor

Comment: Thanks. To make it work I just changed the class from factor to numeric

Comment: @Riccardo If it is for the first column `a`, then you have to follow the `as.numeric(as.character(`  route or `as.numeric(levels(a))[a]`.  I guess you have done in that way

Answer (score 1):

More `data.table`-y solution (after first defining `id` as `as.factor(1000:1200)`), i.e. taking advantage of binary search:

```
setkey(dt,a,b)
dt[.(rep(paste0(1045:1180),2),rep(c("b","c"),each=136)),nomatch=0L]
```

(we have to specify `nomatch` because otherwise we'll just return everything--it would be easier to tell the difference if you had a third variable, which would come back as `NA` for unmatched key combinations)

(of course if you cast `a` as numeric, we don't need the `paste0` bit)

---

An even cleaner way of doing this (without having to specify the recycling ourselves, basically) is with the `CJ` function:

```
setkey(dt,a,b)
dt[CJ(paste0(1045:1180),c("c","d")),nomatch=0L]
```